# Will IntentService finish its job even if the APP (that started it) is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, intentservice

There something not clear to me about IntentService.
I have to perform insert in a Sqlite database.

I do it inside an `IntentService`, to be sure that the `IntentService` will finish its job even if the `Activity` (that started it) is destroyd. Am I right?

What is not clear to me is what will happen to the `IntentService` if the **whole APP** (and not only the `Activity`) is destroyed.
Will the `IntentService` finishes its job even if the App is destroyed?

Thank you

Comment: Using an IntentService you can run long-running operations in the background without affecting the app’s responsiveness and at the same time one of the biggest advantage of it is that, it isn’t affected by most of the user interface (Activity/Fragment) life cycle events, hence continues to run even when the Activity is destroyed for instance. Refer - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: what do you mean by :  whole APP (and not only the Activity) is destroyed ?

Comment: @nomag I mean when the app is no longer alive. For example because closed by the user or terminated by Android (for memory needs). I know the IntentService will keep on doing its job even if the activity is destroyed. I don't know what will happen if the app, from which activity the IntentService was started, is closed/terminated before the IntentService finished its job

Answer (score -1):

When you kill your application all components of your application are killed (activities, services, etc.). If you use Service and return START_STICKY in onStartCommand,  then the OS will recreate the service.

Comment: no one can kill any application except the Android itself.

Comment: please read service documentation before commenting : Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it, is destroyed.

Comment: by going to Manage apps -> App  and force stopping the app doesn't mean killing it ? @user1506104

Comment: He is talking about IntentService . While using service you can play with START_STICKY , START_NOT_STICKY and START_REDELIVER_INTENT . But with IntentService ? @sumit

Comment: @Md.Didarulislam oh yeah, I totally forgot about that :))